# Transport Controls not Updating after MediaPlayerService is destroyed

Tags: java, android, service, android-mediaplayer, wear-os

Okay. I have been struggling with this issue for a while.
Since the latest Wear OS upgrade, a play/pause transport control is displayed in the notification panel instead of showing media controls on a notification. My media player service works fine until it has been paused for some time and android destroys it as it has moved to the background. If the user selects the play button from the transport controls, the music starts playing as it should, but the transport controls no longer update meaning the user can only hit play and can no longer pause. This can be very frustrating if they need to stop audio and can't.

Here is the code where I initialize the media session. This is called at onCreate

```
private void initMediaSession() {
    if (mediaSessionManager != null) return;

    mediaSessionManager = (MediaSessionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
    //Create a new mediaSession
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "com.turndapage.navmusic.mediaplayer");
    //Get mediaSessions Transport Controls
    mediaSession.getController().getTransportControls();
    //Set Mediasession ready to receive media commands
    mediaSession.setActive(true);

    mediaSession.setFlags(
            MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                    MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    callback = new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        // Implement callbacks
        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            super.onPlay();
            Cat.d("Playing from transport controls.");
            // This is the event that is triggered from the transport controls
            resumeMedia();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            Cat.d("Pausing from transport controls");
            pauseMedia();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToNext() {
            super.onSkipToNext();
            skipToNext();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSkipToPrevious() {
            super.onSkipToPrevious();
            skipToPrevious();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(long position) {
            super.onSeekTo(position);
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((int)position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFastForward() {
            super.onFastForward();
            fastForward();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewind() {
            super.onRewind();
            rewind();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayFromMediaId(String mediaId, Bundle extras) {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(mediaId.replace("song", ""));
            int thisIndex = 0;
            for(Song song : songLibrary.getSongs()) {
                if(song.getID() == id) {
                    ArrayList<Song> songs = getCurrentList();
                    thisIndex = songs.indexOf(song);
                    break;
                }
            }
            int[] ids = new int[getCurrentList().size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                ids[i] = getCurrentList().get(i).getID();
            }
            startPlaying(ids, thisIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
            KeyEvent event = mediaButtonEvent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            Cat.e("onMediaButtonEvent called: " + event);
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
                        pauseMedia();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                        playMedia();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
                        //skipToNext();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                        //skipToPrevious();
                        break;
                }
            }
            return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
        }
    };

    // Attach a callback to receive MediaSession update
    mediaSession.setCallback(callback);
    setSessionToken(mediaSession.getSessionToken());
}
```

This method is called when the user clicks the play transport control

```
public void resumeMedia() {
    wasPlaying = true;
    if(mediaPlayer != null) {
        try {
            if (!getPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(resumePosition);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                sendPlayPauseUpdate(true);
                buildNotification(true);
            }
            ComplicationHelper.updatePlayPause(this, true);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            //restoreState();
            startMediaPlayer();
        }
    }
}
```

the send play/pause update just sends a broadcast to the activity to update controls there.

Inside the notification code, I have this to update the playback state of the media session. As you can see, the pause or play actions are only added based on whether the media player is playing or not. Despite this, the play action is still displayed:

```
long actions = MEDIA_SESSION_ACTIONS;
    if(isPlaying)
        actions |= PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE;
    else
        actions |= PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY;
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(actions)
            .setState(isPlaying ? PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING :
                    PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, resumePosition, 1)
            .build());
```

and here are the media session actions:

```
// Media Session Actions
private static final long MEDIA_SESSION_ACTIONS =
        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO |
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS |
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT |
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH |
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PREPARE |
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PREPARE_FROM_SEARCH |
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE |
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP |
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD |
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_REWIND;
```

What I have tried:

- Changing media session to static and back
- making the callback a variable rather than a making a new one when created.
- Manually setting the mediasession's playback state to playing after play from transport controls

This works find on the phone app although I am using a pending intent to send a start command to run the resume function rather than transport controls. I am also able to resume playback from the watch's transport controls if I am using the phone to play audio and the controls update correctly even though the phone app is using the exact same class.

Please let me know if any other information could be helpful.

Thanks!

-Joel

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: No. I reported it as a bug to Google but have not got a solution yet. A workaround though is to just put the playback into paused state and leave it without destroying anything. The Wear OS controls should disappear after about 15 minutes. This isn't ideal, but seems to work.